# sshing with a certificate as root

Tags: rhel, sshd

I seem to have the opposite problem then all the other posts I found during my search.  I can log in as root with a password; but, not with a certificate.  I followed the same steps I have done dozen of times (copy the .pub into the appropriate ~/.ssh/authorized_keys) as both a normal user & root.  It allows me to log in with the certificate as a normal user.  But, it always asks for the password when I try to log in as root.  The network is air-gapped if that makes a difference.  The OS is RHEL 8.

**UPDATE:** I compared the sshd_config & all the pam.d files between a system that works & the air-gapped one that doesn't (Both are running RHEL-8).  The only differences I found were that in the sshd_config, password-auth & system-auth files.  In the sshd_config file, the kewords `LISTENADDRESS`, `Port`, & `PubkeyAuthentication` were commented out on one system & not the other which shouldn't make a difference since the uncommented ones are still set to their default: `0.0.0.0`, `22`, & `yes` respectively.

The *-auth files replaced sha512 with yescrypt.

dosen't work:
`password   sufficient pam_unix.so yescrypt shadow nullok use_authtok`

works:
`password   sufficient       pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok use_authtok`

I will go into the lab tomorrow & change them to the one that works to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: A good first step to debug this sort of issue is to run the ssh server in debug mode (`/usr/sbin/sshd -d`), connect to it, and look at the error messages.

Comment: @larks I will try that the next time I go into the lab.  I am currently comparing all the ssh & pam.d config files with my server at home which allows root to ssh in with both password & certificates.

Comment: What is the version of OpenSSH server? What is the SSH client version? Check the SSH server logs for this error `signature algorithm ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`. If you see that error, this [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/ssh-signature-algorithm-ssh-rsa-error/) will help.